# How to call external JavaScript function into HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 JavaScript files:

`FILE2.js` and  `FILE1.js`

inside FILE1.js are 3 functions:

1. FUNCTION1
2. FUNCTION2
3. FUNCTION3

Question1: How  do I call `FUNCTION2` inside `FUNCTION1`

Question2: Inside `HTML` I include `FILE1` and `FILE2` as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/FILE1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/FILE2.js"></script>
```

How do I make  HTML to know which FILE to use when I need it? and even which FUNCTION in that file?

Thank you and I appreciate. OK here are the codes

```
//return an array of values that match on a certain key
```

FILE1 , function1

```
function function1(obj, key) {
    var community = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            community = community.concat(getValuesCommunity(obj[i], key));
        } else if (i == key) {
            community.push(obj[i]);
        }
    }
return community;
}

// split the string array into corresponding constituent
```

still FILE1, but function2

```
function function2() {    
    community = community.split("/");
    return community
```

Should I call function1 into function2 or the other way round and how is that done?

```
obj==ACTIVITY as shown in the JSON

var ACTIVITIES =
    {"games":
            [
                {"Definition1":
                        [
                            {"SPORTS" : "SPORTS"},
                            {"PHYSICAL SPORTS" : "SPORTS/PHYSICAL SPORTS"},
                            {"MENTAL SPORTS" : "SPORTS/MENTAL SPORTS"},
                            {"COMPUTER GAMES" : "SPORTS/COMPUTER GAMES"},
                            {"more" : "SPORTS/PHYSICAL GAMES/more"},
                            {"and more" : "SPORTS/PHYSICAL GAMES/more/and more"}
                        ]
                },
                {"Definition2":
                        [
                            {"SPORTS" : "SPORTS"},
                            {"name" : "article2"}
                        ]
                }
            ]
    };
```

if I call the JSON

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
                    document.getElementById("loadJSON").innerHTML = getValuesCommunity(ACTIVITIES, "and more");
                }
</script>

<div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Load and Read JSON file</button>
    <p id="loadJSON"></p>
</div>
```

Should give me a list

```
SPORTS,PHYSICAL SPORTS, more, and more
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could post the code you're using.

Comment: @danmullen i have included the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Moved your array otherwise it will be overwritten every time you call function1
var community = [];
function function1(obj, key) {
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            community = community.concat(getValuesCommunity(obj[i], key));
        } else if (i == key) {
            community.push(obj[i]);
        }
    }
//Replaced community with the function call as the function will return the community array.
   return function2();
}

function function2() {    
    community = community.split("/");
    return community
}
```

I did not test your javascript, i simply moved things you asked for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However,  both function1 and function2 are in the same  file. function 1 has an input and its output should be used  by function2

Comment: The answers are here but i think you're having a hard time understanding them. Me and T.J. Crowder have given you the correct answer to your question. If you don't understand then try give more detail on your question or tell us what it is you don't understand. The path of the js file doesn't matter, if those files are linked you can call (any) function linked to your web page.

Comment: You will see my changes answer your question, the code still doesn't look correct to me but it does answer the question you asked so i would appreciate it if you test and mark as answered.
If you still have problems i will type an example to show my changes answer your question.

Comment: Thank you very much. unfortunately I just migrated from python and javascript is a challenge. I have now added the  json file that i wamted to search by KEY 'and more' which should give  me the VALUES [SPORT/PHYSICAL SPORTS/more/and more] and then  function2 splits it into its constituents SPORTS,PHYSICAL SPORTS, more, and more. thanks

Comment: Can you upload your source code to http://fiddle.jshell.net/ each time i answer your question you introduce more code. The answer has been given so this should be marked as aswered. If you want further help i suggest uploading (All) your source code and posting the link.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the functions are globals, you just use their names.

`file1.js`:

```
function function1() {
}
```

`file2.js`:

```
function function2() {
}
```

`file3.js`:

```
function function3() {
    function1(); // <== Example call
}
```

Note that the file containing a function must be included by a `script` tag *before* you call that function (so that the function is defined).

Creating a bunch of globals like that is not generally best practice, though. Instead, consider using just one global and making the functions properties on it:

`file1.js`:

```
var MyApp = MyApp || {};

MyApp.function1 = function() {
};
```

`file2.js`:

```
var MyApp = MyApp || {};

MyApp.function2 = function() {
};
```

`file3.js`:

```
var MyApp = MyApp || {};

MyApp.function3 = function() {
    MyApp.function1(); // <=== Example call
};
```

Or use an AMD (asynchronous module definition) library like RequireJS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in my case file3 does not exist but only function 3 which happen to be  also in  file1. so file1 has 2 functions and I want the results from   function f1 called into function3

Comment: @KevinOluoch: So call `f1` and then feed its result into `function3`: `function3(f1())`

Answer (score -1):

use the javascript instanceof to find the function is valid: for example   if(FUNCTION1 instaceof Function) to decide whether it is loaded.

Comment: Thanks but Im new to javascript, I have  no idea what you mean